# Assign values of list<object> to class variable

Tags: java, arrays, list, loops, object

i want to assign the object that is in the list to the class variables.

I would like in the loop to figure out for itself if the object in the list is of the same type declared in the class

[Image of test loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCRYy.png)

I would not want to manually assign the value to the class variables, but I would like it to understand by itself if the object in the list is the same as the class variable

Thanksss :)

Comment: it's highly recommended to add code and not image with

Answer (score 0):

maybe do something like this:

```
String a = "my string";
Integer b = 5;
List<Object> objectList = List.of(a,b);

objectList.forEach(x-> {
    if (x instanceof String){
        System.out.println(x + " is a string");
        // do something  with x
    } else if (x instanceof Integer){
        System.out.println(x + " is an integer");
        // do something with x
    }
});
```

if you want something more sophisticated, read about Java Reflection

Comment: thank you very much for the answer but I would need a dynamic way to not have to make instance of all objects.

If I have 4 class-level variables, in the loop it has to figure out for itself which is the correct instance and assign the value.

Anyway, thank you for the answer